# Execute ImageMagick convert in subfolders with Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have multiple series of jpegs. Each series is in its own folder. I wish to convert each series into a single pdf. I would further like the pdf to have the same name as the folder it is in.

To do this on the command line in each folder I can use the following command:

```
convert *.jpg `echo ${PWD##*/}`.pdf
```

I would like to do it from the top level folder with a bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `find` for this:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "$0" || exit; shopt -s nullglob; f=( *.jpg ); ((${#f[@]})) && echo convert "${f[@]}" "${PWD##*/}.pdf"' {} \;
```

This will recurse into each subdirectory and for each execute the Bash commands:

```
cd "$0" || exit
shopt -s nullglob
f=( *.jpg )
((${#f[@]})) && echo convert "${f[@]}" "${PWD##*/}.pdf"
```

- The `$0` will expand to the argument given to Bash, i.e., the directory found by `find`. The `exit` is here as a security in case it's impossible to `cd` in there: you don't want to have random commands executed in this case.
- `shopt -s nullglob`: if there are no matches, the globs expand to nothing. Useful if there are subdirectories with no filenames ending in `.jpg`.
- build an array `f` of all the filenames in current directory with a filename ending in `.jpg`. This array is empty if there are no such files (thanks to the `nullglob` shell option).
- If the array `f` is non-empty, execute the command:

  ```
  echo convert "${f[@]}" "${PWD##*/}.pdf"
  ```

  (by the way, your `echo ${PWD##*/}.pdf` is *wrong*, see below).

I put an `echo` in front of `convert`, so that nothing is actually performed; the command is shown on standard output, for you to visually check if everything works as you expect. If this is the case, just remove the `echo`!

---

You asked in a comment: why do you say the following line is wrong?

```
convert *.jpg `echo ${PWD##*/}`.pdf
```

you even say *since it worked*. *To work* and *to be correct* are not equal in computer science. The *it works* sentence should be understood in the full following form: *it works until it fails*. The most obvious case where this fails is if the directory name contains spaces: imagine a directory name of `hello world` then convert will see `hello` as an argument on its own, and `world.pdf` as the last argument. Very likely not what you want. Besides, the following is correct (and shorter and easier to understand):

```
convert *.jpg "${PWD##*/}.pdf"
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much.  I have one question:

1. I don't get what you said about my 'echo ${PWD##*/}.pdf' being wrong since it worked. Could you explain?

For anyone following along in the to put this in a script just paste it in after a line saying '#!/bin/bash' and it works fine.

Comment: @Jack added a small note regarding why your echo part is wrong.