# Bash convert resize recursively preserving filenames

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, subdirectory

Have images in subfolders that need to be limited in size (720 max width or 1100 max height). Their filenames must be preserved. Started with:

```
for img in *.jpg; do filename=${img%.*}; convert -resize 720x1100\> "$filename.jpg" "$filename.jpg"; done
```

which works within each directory, but have a lot of subfolders with these images. Tried `find . -iname "*.jpg" -exec cat {}` but it did not create a list as expected.

This also didn't work:

```
grep *.jpg | while read line ; do `for img in *.jpg; do filename=${img%.jpg}; convert -resize 720x1100\> "$filename.jpg" "$filename.jpg"`; done
```

Neither did this:

```
find . -iname '*jpg' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do convert -resize 720x1100\> $line; done
```

which gives me error message "convert: no images defined." And then:

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} convert -resize 720x1100\> {}
```

gives me the same error message.

Comment: If you are using Bash 4 then you can easily modify your first attempt to process all jpg files in the directory tree: `shopt -s globstar ; for img in **/*.jpg ; do ... ; done`.

Comment: Also tried `find . -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "$0" || exit; shopt -s nullglob; f=( *.jpg ); ((${#f[@]})) && echo convert -resize 640x1100\> "${f[@]}" "${f[@]}"' {} \;` based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311384/execute-imagemagick-convert-in-subfolders-with-bash-script

Comment: I upgraded Bash and got convert: unable to open image `'**/*.jpg'`: No such file or directory.

Comment: Ah! I was missing a subdirectory level... This worked Thanks so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you're looking for simply this:

```
find /path/to/dir -name '*.jpg' -exec mogrify -resize 720x1100\> {} \;
```

In your examples, you strip the `.jpg` extension, and then you add it back. No need to strip at all, and that simplifies things a lot.
Also, `convert filename filename` is really the same as `mogrify filename`. `mogrify` is part of ImageMagick, it's useful for modifying files in-place, overwriting the original file. `convert` is useful for creating new files, preserving originals.

Comment: Thanks. I've had bad luck with mogrify in the past; hence, hesitant to use it. But this worked great and is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since all of the subdirectories are two levels down, found this worked:

```
for img in **/*/*.jpg ; do filename=${img%.*}; convert -resize 720x1100\> "$filename.jpg" "$filename.jpg"; done
```

Thanks to @pjh for getting me started. This also worked:

```
shopt -s globstar ; for img in */*/*.jpg ; do filename=${img%.*}; convert -resize 720x1100\> "$filename.jpg" "$filename.jpg"; done
```

But I got the error message "-bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name" but all of the images larger than specified were resized with filenames preserved.

Comment: The real question, however, is how to search all levels of directories.